# How do I make objects *not* move when I have animation?

Tags: java, swing

In swing graphics, I need to make something where the stick figure moves back and forth, but something stays put. I'm using the blue horizontal line as a test. It doesn't move, but it disappears in time with the stick figure's sword. How do I stop that?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class AnimatedBoxman extends JApplet  implements Runnable,ActionListener
{   
   int size=50;

   int x = 0;
   int y =300;
   int side2side = 50;

   Thread t;
   boolean sworddrawn = false;
   JButton myButton = new JButton("Change");
   static Random myRan = new Random();
   public void init()
   {

       Container content = getContentPane();
         content.setBackground(Color.red);
         setLayout(new FlowLayout());
         add(myButton);
         myButton.addActionListener(this);


   }
   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
   {
      side2side= -side2side;
     Container content = getContentPane();
     content.setBackground(new Color 
        (Math.abs(myRan.nextInt())%256,
         Math.abs(myRan.nextInt())%256,
         Math.abs(myRan.nextInt())%256));

     repaint();
   }
   public void run( )
   {
     while( true )
     {
      x+= side2side;
      if (x > this.getSize().width-50 || x < 0)
          side2side = -side2side;
      if (x%3 == 0)
          sworddrawn = !sworddrawn;
      repaint( );
      try {
          Thread.sleep(900);
      }
      catch( Exception e ) { }
     }
   }
   public void start( )
   {
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start( );
   }

   public void paint ( Graphics g )
   {
     super.paint( g );

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(x-10, y, x-30,y);
        g.drawLine(x-30, y, x-30, y-20);
        g.drawLine(x-10, y-20, x-10, y);


        g.drawLine(x-10, y-20, x+10, y-20);
        g.drawLine(x-10, y-20, x+10, y-20);
        g.drawLine(x-10, y, x+10, y);
        g.drawLine(x-10, y, x-10, y+20);
        g.drawLine(x, y+20, x, y);
        g.drawLine(x+10, y+20,x+10, y);

        g.drawLine(x+10, y, x+30, y);
        g.drawLine(x+30, y, x+30, y-20);
        g.drawLine(x+10, y-20, x+10, y);

        g.drawLine(x, y+20, x+10, y+20);
        g.drawLine(x-10, y+20, x-10, y+30);
        g.drawLine(x-10, y+30, x, y+30);
        g.drawLine(x, y+30, x, y+20);
        g.drawLine(x, y+30, x+10, y+30);
        g.drawLine(x+10, y+30, x+10, y+20);
        g.drawLine(x-10, y+20, x, y+20);
        g.drawOval(x-7, y-20, 5, 5);
        g.drawOval(x+1, y-20, 5, 5);
        g.drawLine(x-4, y-8, x-5, y-5);
        g.drawLine(x-5, y-8, x+6, y-8);
        g.drawLine(x+6, y-5, x+6, y-8);


     if( sworddrawn )
     {
         g.drawLine(500, 400, 700, 400);
         }
     else
     {


            Polygon myPolygon2;
            myPolygon2=new Polygon();
            myPolygon2.addPoint(x-42,y-184);
            myPolygon2.addPoint(x-32,y-195);
            myPolygon2.addPoint(x-21,y-184);
            g.fillPolygon(myPolygon2);
            g.fillRect(x-41, y-184, 20, 100);
            g.fillArc(x-50, y-104, 40, 20, 180, 180);
            g.fillArc(x-35, y-94, 20, 35, 90, 180);
            g.drawLine(x-30, y-164, x-30, y-24);

            g.drawOval(x-40, y-24, 20, 30);

     }

   }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "How do I stop that?"

Answer (score 0):

The blue horizontal line can be outside of the content pane, in which case it is not drawn. You can check the size of the content pane by adding a line to the `init` method:

```
System.out.println("getSize(): " + getSize());
```

On my laptop, the size is 400 by 300 pixels:

```
getSize(): java.awt.Dimension[width=400,height=300]
```

This results in an invisible blue horizontal line:

```
g.drawLine(500, 400, 700, 400);
```

With lower values for x and y coordinates, the line is visible:

```
g.drawLine(50, 40, 70, 40);
```

Finally, when you ask a question it can be useful to add a screenshot of your application with some additional text to explain what your problem is (for example, what you expect versus what you see).